# Magento 2.2.6 Incompatible argument type

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.2.6

I am getting the following error when running the command:

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

```
----------
 Test\Firstmodule\Model\Adminhtml\Config\Data
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Reader\Source\Deployed\SettingChecker. Actual type: array; File:
/public_html/app/code/Test/Firstmodule/Model/Adminhtml/Config/Data.php

Total Errors Count: 1
```

**The file data.php is overriding the file config.php in \Magento\Config\Model:**

```
namespace Test\FirstModule\Model\Adminhtml\Config;
class Data extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config
{
/**
 * Save config section
 * Require set: section, website, store and groups
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data
 */
protected $_objectManager;
/**
 * Config data for sections
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_configData;

/**
 * Event dispatcher
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
 */
protected $_eventManager;

/**
 * System configuration structure
 *
 * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure
 */
protected $_configStructure;

/**
 * Application config
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $_appConfig;

/**
 * Global factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $_objectFactory;

/**
 * TransactionFactory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory
 */
protected $_transactionFactory;

/**
 * Config data loader
 *
 * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Loader
 */
protected $_configLoader;

/**
 * Config data factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory
 */
protected $_configValueFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

protected $_request;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ReinitableConfigInterface $config
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure $configStructure
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
 * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Loader $configLoader
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ReinitableConfigInterface $config,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure $configStructure,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Loader $configLoader,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    array $data = []
)
{

    parent::__construct($config, $eventManager, $configStructure, $transactionFactory, $configLoader, $configValueFactory, $storeManager, $data);

    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_request = $request;
}

protected function _processGroup(
    $groupId,
    array $groupData,
    array $groups,
    $sectionPath,
    array &$extraOldGroups,
    array &$oldConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $saveTransaction,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $deleteTransaction
)
{


    $groupPath = $sectionPath . '/' . $groupId;
    $scope = $this->getScope();
    $scopeId = $this->getScopeId();
    $scopeCode = $this->getScopeCode();


    /**
     *
     * Map field names if they were cloned
     */
    /** @var $group \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group */
    $group = $this->_configStructure->getElement($groupPath);


    // set value for group field entry by fieldname
    // use extra memory
    $fieldsetData = [];
    if (isset($groupData['fields'])) {
        if ($group->shouldCloneFields()) {
            $cloneModel = $group->getCloneModel();
            $mappedFields = [];

            /** @var $field \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field */
            foreach ($group->getChildren() as $field) {
                foreach ($cloneModel->getPrefixes() as $prefix) {
                    $mappedFields[$prefix['field'] . $field->getId()] = $field->getId();
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($groupData['fields'] as $fieldId => $fieldData) {
            $fieldsetData[$fieldId] = is_array(
                $fieldData
            ) && isset(
                $fieldData['value']
            ) ? $fieldData['value'] : null;
        }

        foreach ($groupData['fields'] as $fieldId => $fieldData) {
            $originalFieldId = $fieldId;
            if ($group->shouldCloneFields() && isset($mappedFields[$fieldId])) {
                $originalFieldId = $mappedFields[$fieldId];
            }
            /** @var $field \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field */
            $field = $this->_configStructure->getElement($groupPath . '/' . $originalFieldId);

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueInterface $backendModel */
            $backendModel = $field->hasBackendModel() ? $field
                ->getBackendModel() : $this
                ->_configValueFactory
                ->create();

            $data = [
                'field' => $fieldId,
                'groups' => $groups,
                'group_id' => $group->getId(),
                'scope' => $scope,
                'scope_id' => $scopeId,
                'scope_code' => $scopeCode,
                'field_config' => $field->getData(),
                'fieldset_data' => $fieldsetData
            ];


            $backendModel->addData($data);

            $this->_checkSingleStoreMode($field, $backendModel);

            if (false == isset($fieldData['value'])) {
                $fieldData['value'] = null;
            }

            $path = $field->getGroupPath() . '/' . $fieldId;
            $vendorId = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('data_com');

            /**
             * Look for custom defined field path
             */
            if ($field && $field->getConfigPath()) {
                $configPath = $field->getConfigPath();
                if (!empty($configPath) && strrpos($configPath, '/') > 0) {
                    // Extend old data with specified section group
                    $configGroupPath = substr($configPath, 0, strrpos($configPath, '/'));
                    if ($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Module\Manager')->isEnabled('Test_FmCommission')) {
                        if ($vendorId) {
                            $configGroupPath = $vendorId . '/' . $configGroupPath;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isset($extraOldGroups[$configGroupPath])) {
                        $oldConfig = $this->extendConfig($configGroupPath, true, $oldConfig);
                        $extraOldGroups[$configGroupPath] = true;
                    }
                    $path = $configPath;

                }
            }

            $inherit = !empty($fieldData['inherit']);
            $oldpath = $path;
            $vendorId = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('data_com');

            if ($vendorId) {
                $path = $vendorId . '/' . $path;
            }

            $groupDatas = $this->_request->getPost();
            $gcode = isset($groupDatas['group_code']) && strlen($groupDatas['group_code']) > 0 ? $groupDatas['group_code'] : ($this->_request->getParam('gcode', false) ? $this->_request->getParam('gcode') : '');
            if (strlen($gcode) > 0) {
                $path = $gcode . '/' . $path;
            }
            $backendModel->setPath($path)->setValue($fieldData['value']);
            if (isset($oldConfig[$path])) {
                $backendModel->setConfigId($oldConfig[$path]['config_id']);

                /**
                 * Delete config data if inherit
                 */
                if (!$inherit) {
                    $saveTransaction->addObject($backendModel);
                } else {
                    $deleteTransaction->addObject($backendModel);
                }
            }
            if (isset($oldConfig[$oldpath])) {
                $backendModel->setConfigId($oldConfig[$oldpath]['config_id']);

                /**
                 * Delete config data if inherit
                 */
                if (!$inherit) {
                    $saveTransaction->addObject($backendModel);
                } else {
                    $deleteTransaction->addObject($backendModel);
                }
            } elseif (!$inherit) {
                $backendModel->unsConfigId();
                $saveTransaction->addObject($backendModel);
            }
            $deleteTransaction->delete();
            $saveTransaction->save();
        }
    }

    if (isset($groupData['groups'])) {
        foreach ($groupData['groups'] as $subGroupId => $subGroupData) {
            $this->_processGroup(
                $subGroupId,
                $subGroupData,
                $groups,
                $groupPath,
                $extraOldGroups,
                $oldConfig,
                $saveTransaction,
                $deleteTransaction
            );
        }
    }

}

public function load()
{
    $is_csgroup = $this->_request->getParams('is_csgroup');
    if (!$is_csgroup) return parent::load();
    $this->initScope();
    $this->_configData = $this->_getConfig(false);
    return $this->_configData;
}

public function extendConfig($path, $full = true, $oldConfig = [])
{
    $extended = $this->getConfigByPath($path, $this->getScope(), $this->getScopeId(), $full);
    if (is_array($oldConfig) && !empty($oldConfig)) {
        return $oldConfig + $extended;
    }
    return $extended;
}

/**
 * Add data by path section/group/field
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return void
 * @throws \UnexpectedValueException
 */
public function setDataByPath($path, $value)
{
    $path = trim($path);
    if ($path === '') {
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Path must not be empty');
    }
    $pathParts = explode('/', $path);
    $keyDepth = count($pathParts);
    if ($keyDepth !== 3) {
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException(
            "Allowed depth of configuration is 3 (<section>/<group>/<field>). Your configuration depth is "
            . $keyDepth . " for path '$path'"
        );
    }
    $data = [
        'section' => $pathParts[0],
        'groups' => [
            $pathParts[1] => [
                'fields' => [
                    $pathParts[2] => ['value' => $value],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $this->addData($data);
}


/**
 * Get scope name and scopeId
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
private function initScope()
{
    $is_csgroup = $this->_request->getParams('is_csgroup');
    if (!$is_csgroup) {
        if ($this->getSection() === null) {
            $this->setSection('');
        }
        if ($this->getWebsite() === null) {
            $this->setWebsite('');
        }
        if ($this->getStore() === null) {
            $this->setStore('');
        }

        if ($this->getStore()) {
            $scope = 'stores';
            $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore($this->getStore());
            $scopeId = (int)$store->getId();
            $scopeCode = $store->getCode();
        } elseif ($this->getWebsite()) {
            $scope = 'websites';
            $website = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite($this->getWebsite());
            $scopeId = (int)$website->getId();
            $scopeCode = $website->getCode();
        } else {
            $scope = 'default';
            $scopeId = 0;
            $scopeCode = '';
        }
        $this->setScope($scope);
        $this->setScopeId($scopeId);
        $this->setScopeCode($scopeCode);
    } else {
        if ($this->getStore()) {
            $scope = 'stores';
            $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore($this->getStore());
            $scopeId = (int)$store->getId();
            $scopeCode = $store->getCode();
        } elseif ($this->getWebsite()) {
            $scope = 'websites';
            $website = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite($this->getWebsite());
            $scopeId = (int)$website->getId();
            $scopeCode = $website->getCode();
        } else {
            $scope = 'default';
            $scopeId = 0;
            $scopeCode = '';
        }
        $this->setScope($scope);
        $this->setScopeId($scopeId);
        $this->setScopeCode($scopeCode);
    }

}

/**
 * Return formatted config data for current section
 *
 * @param bool $full Simple config structure or not
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getConfig($full = true)
{
    $is_csgroup = $this->_request->getParams('is_csgroup');
    if (!$is_csgroup) return parent::_getConfig($full);
    $groupData = $this->_request->getPost();
    $gcode = isset($groupData['group_code']) && strlen($groupData['group_code']) > 0 ? $groupData['group_code'] : ($this->_request->getParam('gcode', false) ? $this->_request->getParam('gcode') : '');
    if (strlen($gcode) > 0) {
        return $this->getConfigByPath($this->getSection(), $this->getScopeId(), $full);
    } else {
        return parent::_getConfig($full);
    }
}

/**
 * Set correct scope if isSingleStoreMode = true
 *
 * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field $fieldConfig
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueInterface $dataObject
 * @return void
 */
protected function _checkSingleStoreMode(
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field $fieldConfig,
    $dataObject
)
{
    $isSingleStoreMode = $this->_storeManager->isSingleStoreMode();
    if (!$isSingleStoreMode) {
        return;
    }
    if (!$fieldConfig->showInDefault()) {
        $websites = $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
        $singleStoreWebsite = array_shift($websites);
        $dataObject->setScope('websites');
        $dataObject->setWebsiteCode($singleStoreWebsite->getCode());
        $dataObject->setScopeCode($singleStoreWebsite->getCode());
        $dataObject->setScopeId($singleStoreWebsite->getId());
    }
}

/**
 * Get config data value
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param null|bool &$inherit
 * @param null|array $configData
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Simplexml\Element
 */
public function getConfigDataValue($path, &$inherit = null, $configData = null)
{
    $this->load();
    if ($configData === null) {
        $configData = $this->_configData;
    }

    if (isset($configData[$path])) {
        $data = $configData[$path];
        $inherit = false;
    } else {
        $data = $this->_appConfig->getValue($path, $this->getScope(), $this->getScopeCode());
        $inherit = true;
    }

    return $data;
}

protected function getConfigByPath($path, $scope, $scopeId, $full = true)
{
    $is_csgroup = $this->_request->getParams('is_csgroup');

    switch ($is_csgroup) {
        case 1:
            $groupData = $this->_request->getPost();
            $gcode = isset($groupData['group_code']) && strlen($groupData['group_code']) > 0 ? $groupData['group_code'] : ($this->_request->getParam('gcode', false) ? $this->_request->getParam('gcode') : '');
            if (strlen($gcode) > 0) {
                $path = $gcode . '/' . $path;
            }
            break;
        case 2 :
            $vendorId = $this->_request->getParam('vendor_id', 0);
            $vendor = $this->_objectManager->get('Test\FirstModule\Model\Vendor')->load($vendorId);
            if ($vendor && $vendor->getId()) {
                $path = $vendor->getId() . '/' . $path;
            }
    }

    $configDataCollection = $this->_configValueFactory->create()->getCollection()
                            ->addScopeFilter($this->getScope(), $this->getScopeId(), $path);

    $config = [];
    foreach ($configDataCollection as $data) {
        if ($full) {
            $config[$data->getPath()] = array(
                'path' => $data->getPath(),
                'value' => $data->getValue(),
                'config_id' => $data->getConfigId()
            );
        } else {
            $config[$data->getPath()] = $data->getValue();
        }
    }
    return $config;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in

`/public_html/app/code/Test/Firstmodule/Model/Adminhtml/Config/Data.php`

Hard to know without seeing the code as it looks like a custom config source model.

Here is something I put together.  Check you are implementing correct class and used correct syntax for constructor and methods.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Magento2-AutoInvoice/blob/master/app/code/Xigen/AutoInvoice/Model/Config/Source/Payments.php

Payments.php

app/code/Xigen/AutoInvoice/Model/Config/Source/Payments.php

```php
namespace Xigen\AutoInvoice\Model\Config\Source;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Config;
class Payments implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface
     * @param Config               $paymentModelConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface,
        Config $paymentModelConfig
    ) {
        $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface = $appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
        $this->_paymentModelConfig = $paymentModelConfig;
    }
    /**
     * toOptionArray.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $payments = $this->_paymentModelConfig->getActiveMethods();
        $methods = [];
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {
            $paymentTitle = $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface
                ->getValue('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            $methods[$paymentCode] = [
                'label' => $paymentTitle,
                'value' => $paymentCode,
            ];
        }
        return $methods;
    }
}
```

*Update*

Now I see your code I understand more on what's happening.  Have you checked the differences between 2.2.4 and 2.2.6 in core Magento\Config\Model\Data. You might have to merge some 2.2.6 changes in. That's as much advice as I can give you. This could be tricky to resolve.

Comment: Please check the code i attached it shows the contents of file data.php. The code was working on version 2.2.4 but when updated to version 2.2.6 i got the following error